# How to pass PrimgNg selected checkboxes down to child component dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a simple app using PrimeNg. Using a Parent and Child component, I am trying to pass information from the selected items of the Parent's Multi-Select ( `<p-multiSelect/>` ) down to the child's Dropdown (`<p-dropdown/>`).

I am trying to get it so the selected items in the multi-select appear as the only options in the dropdown. The issue here is that PrimeNg Components need a label and a value. Passing down these selected items only results in passing down a value, so the dropdown appears blank.

[image]

This is what the PrimeNg dropdown requires and what is being used in the multi-select:

```
statements = [
  { label: 'Item1', value: 'item1' },
  { label: 'item2', value: 'item2' },
  { label: 'Item3', value: 'item3' },
  { label: 'Item4', value: 'item4' },
  { label: 'Item5', value: 'item5' },
];
```

Using `[(ngModel)]='selectedStatements` on the parent's multiSelect, I am passing the selected items  into the child component `app-select-statement` with the `@Input() statements;`. This works just as expected because I *am* getting the data passed down to my child component.

```
<div>
    <p-multiSelect 
    [options]="statements" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedStatements">
    </p-multiSelect>

    <app-select-statements [statements]='selectedStatements'></app-select-statements>
</div>
```

As mentioned above, however, the dropdown items are blank because the @Input on the child component is only receiving a value and not a value and a label as required for PrimeNg's Dropdown component.

Is there any way to get all the information from the multiSelect so the dropdown in the child component is populated?

[HERE is a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-gg8zc8) with all code

#### AppComponent.ts

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  statements = [
    { label: 'Item1', value: 'item1' },
    { label: 'item2', value: 'item2' },
    { label: 'Item3', value: 'item3' },
    { label: 'Item4', value: 'item4' },
    { label: 'Item5', value: 'item5' },
  ];
}
```

#### select-statements.ts (child component)

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-statements',
  template: `
    <div> 
      <p-dropdown 
        placeholder="Choose"
        [options]="statements"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class StatementComponent {
  @Input() statements;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

output of primeng selected is string array not object array.So you need to map it inside ngOnChanges in child component

```
export class StatementComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() statements;
  ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.statements){
        this.statements=this.statements.map(v => ({ "label": v,"value":v }));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great and as expected